# Trying to replicate Python's struct.unpack ">L" in JavaScript with TypedArrays

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to reproduce the following Python code in JavaScript.

```
import struct
val = struct.unpack(">L", "MACS")[0]
```

`val` is now `1296122707` (the same as `0x4d414353`). Trying the same with `htk1` gives `1752460081`, the same as `0x68746b31`.

I was trying to bring this to JavaScript so I got to studying and came across this documentation on Python: [`classmethod int.from_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes).

So the above is the same as:

```
int.from_bytes(b"MACS", "big")
```

However I am not able to port it to JavaScript. How can I make a start on doing so, or is it already available out there?

Here was my attempt:

```
function unpackL(fourCharCode) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(8);
    var view = new DataView(buf);
    view.setUint8(0, String.charCodeAt(fourCharCode[0]), true);
    view.setUint8(2, String.charCodeAt(fourCharCode[1]), true);
    view.setUint8(4, String.charCodeAt(fourCharCode[2]), true);
    view.setUint8(6, String.charCodeAt(fourCharCode[3]), true);
    return new Uint32Array(buf);
}
```

However `unpackL('htk1')` gives me `Uint32Array [ 7602280, 3211371 ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function that does this (returning undefined if the string is the wrong length):

```
function stringToUnsignedInt(string) {
  if (string.length !== 4) {
    return undefined;
  }

  return (string.charCodeAt(0) << 24) +
         (string.charCodeAt(1) << 16) +
         (string.charCodeAt(2) << 8) +
         string.charCodeAt(3);
}

console.log(stringToUnsignedInt("MACS") === 1296122707); // true
console.log(stringToUnsignedInt("htk1") === 1752460081); // true
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks for the super fast reply! I remember you because you helped me with `?raw=1` for dropbox api images in img src thags. Thanks for this!